# KML balloon styling

Tags: google-maps, kml, balloon

I read several ways to alter what appears in the balloons on google maps. I am uploading from a KML file. I want to get rid of the directions/Search nearby links on the bottom of the balloon. I have tried some variations of the KML below but it seems to have no effect on the balloon.

```
 <Style id='removal'>
      <BalloonStyle>
           <text>$[description]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
 </Style>
<Placemark>
    <name>elephant</name>
    <description>These are two elephants, one big and one small
            </description>  
            <styleUrl>#removal</styleUrl>   
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-121.985621 , 37.220577</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the age of this question, I assume this has been resolve somehow, but since it's still out there: I'm pretty sure there is no such option if you upload KML directly to Maps, but if you create an overlay from your own page with JavaScript like described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), the balloons will not have the Search Nearby links in them.